# Catch route parameter using ?param=value format

Tags: jquery, parameters, routes

I understand how I can pass parameters from a route to a controller using for example

```
Route::get('getAllUsers/{term}', 'MethodController@fetchUserList');
```

However, in a JavaScript I wrote I use the jQuery autocomplete widget which ALWAYS calls a any URL by automatically appending ?term=searchterm. I need to catch this parameter in my route, but Laravel doesn' let me do something like this:

```
Route::get('getAllUsers?term={term}', 'MethodController@fetchUserList');
```

How can I catch that parameter and pass it to the controller?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

It's a primitive get parameter. You can get it with `\Input::get('term')` .
More in-depth info http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input .

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Can I just concatenate this like this:
Route::get('getAllUsers\Input::get('term', 'MethodController@fetchUserList');
and pass it forward to the fetchUserList function (which expects the parameter "term"?
Or is something missing?

Comment: Ok got it:
Route::get('getAllUsers', function() {
    $term = Input::get('term');
    //
}

Thanks!